# How to summarise datetime by a specific time interval?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to summarise the datetime to a 6 AM and 6 PM by taking the maximum value in 'count' column and it's type. If there is no value in count column then it should be filled with zero with a type 'low'.

input

```
datetime,count,type
1/1/19 0:00,1,medium
1/1/19 1:00,2,medium      
1/1/19 2:00,3,medium
1/3/19 21:00,1,medium
1/3/19 22:00,2,medium
1/4/19 0:00,3,medium
1/4/19 1:00,4,medium
1/4/19 2:00,5,medium
1/4/19 3:00,6,high
```

Output

```
date    time    count      type
1/1/19  6:00 AM 3       medium
1/1/19  6:00 PM 0       low
1/2/19  6:00 AM 0       low
1/2/19  6:00 PM 0       low
1/3/19  6:00 AM 0       low
1/3/19  6:00 PM 0       low
1/4/19  6:00 AM 6       high
1/4/19  6:00 PM 0       low
```

I tried something like this

```
input1 = input1.set_index('datetime')
input1 = input1.sort_index()
input1 = input1.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = '12H', base=6))
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
input.resample('12H', on='datetime', base=6, label='right').count()
```